# Preparing multiple URLs for webscraping with rvest in R

Tags: html, r, string, csv, rvest

I get inconsistent results scraping multiple URLs with `rvest`. A concatenated string of URLs returns a character vector. Running the `html_nodes` returns three different results.

```
library(rvest)
 url <- c("https://interestingengineering.com/due-to-the-space-inside-atoms-you-are-mostly- 
          made-up-of-empty-space",
          "https://futurism.com/mit-tech-self-driving-cars-see-under-surface-road",
          "https://techxplore.com/news/2020-02-socially-robot-children-autism.html",
          "https://eos.org/science-updates/hackathon-speeds-progress-toward-climate-model- 
          collaboration",
          "https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/new-study-finds-people-prefer-robots- 
           explain-themselves-180974299/",
           "https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/02/200227144259.htm")

      page <-map(url, ~read_html(.x) %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text())
```

This code will either return extracted content from all the URLs.

Or it will give this error message:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
>     Error while processing content unencoding: invalid code lengths set

Or this error message:

> Error during wrapup: HTTP error 410.

After the last error message, I also get Browse[1]> in the console.

I tried to run the URLs from a CSV file:

```
   urldoc<- read.csv("URLs for rvest.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",")
   page <-map(urldoc, ~read_html(.x) %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text())
```

The `print(urldoc)` output looks similar to the one from the concatenated code, but I get a different error message:

> Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
>     Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=83]

I can't run the `html_node` or `html_text`on the data frame.

1) How can I get an error-free consistent return.
2) Even better, how can I use a document with URLs instead of concatenated string?

Comment: Your current vector of "urls" contain some line breaks within the url itself and that will cause errors.  Once I corrected that, I can't reproduce your errors up above.  Error 410 unusual means an invalid page, so double check that all of your urls are correct.  Your final issue, ensure each url on a single line and only 1 url per line in your csv file.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, even after cleaning up the csv I get the same error. It won't accept the vector and demands a single string value instead. It works when I run them concatenated, but I run into HTTP problems. I guess the scraping stop when it runs into a non-working url., so I will need to find a way to ignore those urls.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your first issue was caused by line breaks on your URLs.

As for your second question: I could reproduce your issue reading from the .csv.
Here's the solution I found.

```
urldoc<- read.csv("URLs for rvest.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",", header=FALSE)
page <-map(urldoc[,1], ~read_html(.x) %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text())
```

Make sure your .csv only has one URL per line, and specify the column you want to read from.

Comment: Thanks. I cleaned up the csv a bit and made sure to subset the column with urls. Unfortunately, the error persists, though.